# Unable to call connection string from web config file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to establish a connection with sql database. I want to place the connection string in the `web config` file. So i wrote the code in the web config file as:

```
<add name="DBCS" connectionString="data source=sahil-pc\\sqlexpress; database=abadakDb; Integrated Security=true " providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Now, I want to establish the connection in the asp.net, so i wrote a method in my cs file as:

```
 private DataSet getData(string procName, SqlParameter param)

    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(procName, conn);

        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        da.Fill(ds);

        return ds;

    }
```

Here, i am getting the error in the da.Fill(ds) line. It says

`System.InvalidOperationException: Instance failure`.

I checked the code from the internet. I dont know where I am going wrong. 
If I explicitly write the connection string in the function then it works fine. So the problem is with connection string in the web config file or the calling thing to web config file. Can you please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your connection string in the web.config to:

```
"data source=sahil-pc\sqlexpress; database=abadakDb; Integrated Security=true " providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

in code, the \\ resolves to \, it comes in exactly as is from the web.config

the same as putting a literal @ before the string

Comment: yes it worked now. But cant i put, "datasource=.;" if it is a local sql database. ?

Comment: yes, but for a named instance (like sqlexpress) you'd need to specify the instance datasource=.\sqlexpress

Comment: ok..then when should i put "." ?? if it is a sql authentication ??

Comment: if you want to use the default instance of sql server. It has nothing to do with authentication.  It is just a shortcut indicating the local machine